# Text length limit not working in my instafeed template

Tags: javascript, instafeedjs

Hi I got a template for instafeed and now I need to limit the length of the caption. I added to js code to do it but it does not work. Is there a way to make the `<p><i>{{caption}}</i></p>` shorter and add ellipsis.

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
            $(".caption").each(function(i){
                len=$(this).text().length;
                if(len>10)
                {
                    $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,10)+'...');
                }
            });
        });

        /* Intafeed and SimplyScroll */
        var feed = new Instafeed({
            target: 'instagram-list',
            get: 'user',
            userId: 1713392078,
            accessToken: '0000000',
            clientId: '0000000',
            limit: '30',
            sortBy: 'most-recent',
            link: 'true',
            template: '<li><figure class="effect-honey background-black1"><figcaption><p><i class"caption">{{caption}}</i></p></figcaption><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" alt"{{caption}}"/></a><span class="instagram-metadata shadow">{{likes}} <span class="instagram-like"></span></span></figure></li>',
            resolution: 'low_resolution',
            after: function() {
                $("#instagram-list").simplyScroll({
                    speed: 1,
                    frameRate: 24,
                    orientation: 'horizontal',
                    direction: 'forwards',
                })
            }
        })

        feed.run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish using the built in `filter` option that Instafeed.js provides.

Even though the `filter` option is primarily used for filtering images, you can also use it to modify image data before it gets sent to your `template` string.

So update your Instafeed.js settings with the following:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    target: 'instagram-list',
    get: 'user',
    userId: 1713392078,
    accessToken: '0000000',
    clientId: '0000000',
    limit: '30',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    link: 'true',
    filter: function(image) {
      var MAX_LENGTH = 10;

      // here we create a property called "short_caption"
      // on the image object, using the original caption
      if (image.caption && image.caption.text) {
        image.short_caption = image.caption.text.slice(0, MAX_LENGTH);
      } else {
        image.short_caption = "";
      }

      // ensure the filter doesn't reject any images
      return true;
    },

    template: '<li><figure class="effect-honey background-black1"><figcaption><p><i class"caption">{{model.short_caption}}</i></p></figcaption><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" alt"{{model.short_caption}}"/></a><span class="instagram-metadata shadow">{{likes}} <span class="instagram-like"></span></span></figure></li>',
    resolution: 'low_resolution',
    after: function() {
        $("#instagram-list").simplyScroll({
            speed: 1,
            frameRate: 24,
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            direction: 'forwards',
        })
    }
})

feed.run();
```

This will assign a new property to each image called `short_caption`. You can then use `{{model.short_caption}}` in place of `{{caption}}` inside your `template` string.

(Set the `MAX_LENGTH` variable to be the maximum caption length you want)

---

**Update based on comments:** If you want to limit your text based on the closest word ending, you'll have to add some more logic into your filter. Since the filter function is just plain JavaScript, you can add any kind of logic you want there.

Here's a quick example of one way you can find the closest word ending of a substring in plain JavaScript:

```js
var MAX_LENGTH = 100;

var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lobortis felis dolor, in volutpat erat hendrerit ut. Mauris auctor quam at nulla tincidunt aliquam. Vivamus facilisis adipiscing lacus, vel dignissim nulla imperdiet nec. Donec fermentum, urna vel adipiscing vehicula, ante odio scelerisque tortor, vitae auctor eros tortor eu massa";
var trimmedText;

var closestIndex = MAX_LENGTH;
while(true) {
  if (text.charAt(closestIndex) === ' ') {
    break;
  }
  closestIndex -= 1;
}

trimmedText = text.slice(0, closestIndex) + '...';

alert(trimmedText)
```

So update your `filter` function with the additional logic, modified from the example I showed you above:

```
filter: function(image) {
  var MAX_LENGTH = 100;
  var closestIndex = MAX_LENGTH;

  if (image.caption && image.caption.text) {
    while(true) {
      if (text.charAt(closestIndex) === ' ') {
        break;
      }
      closestIndex -= 1;
    }
    image.short_caption = image.caption.text.slice(0, MAX_LENGTH);
  } else {
    image.short_caption = "";
  }

  return true;
},
```

Comment: It work fine Steven. Thank you! But do you know if with this method is possible to end the word so that assassination does not become ass. :D

Comment: @JoanManuelHernández Extended my answer based on your addition.

Answer (score 0):

use [pure css](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) to truncate text and add ellipsis, it will be faster and more maintainable

There are .js libraries for rendering text ellipsis (for example [jquery.ellipsis](https://github.com/jjenzz/jquery.ellipsis))

Comment: I would prefer to do it with js. If it were possible.

Comment: @JoanManuelHernández, ok added a jquery plugin for ellipsis